# Finding a Standard Button (RequestUseSfdc) that is being excluded from page layouts?

Tags: metadata-api, page-layout, contact, data.com

In the metadata file for [layouts](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_layouts.htm), you'll see that standard buttons are only specified for those that shouldn't display: through a `<excludeButtons>` field. The description states:

> List of standard buttons to exclude from this layout. For example, Delete excludes the Delete button from this layout.

I figured it would be easy to find these references since you could look through a given object's buttons/actions and see what's "standard" and understand what it's doing/related to.  However, there's one showing up in my diffs that I can't seem to find any reference to.

`RequestUseSfdc` is being excluded on Contact layouts in production, but not in sandboxes. It seems even if I deploy it without the exclusions into productions, they still stay there.

I found one [question](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F00000008knCIAQ) from 2010 that references it, but provided no answer to specify what it is.

I've done a couple things:

1. Hovered over all the actions/buttons in the layout editor to see if it showed. I found all other excluded buttons except that one.
2. Did a search through our metadata repository and could only find references to this on the contact layout.

The *only* hunch I have is that it's related to DataDotCom. We don't use it, but it's possible we used it once or it's "on" because of prior usage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was the [Check for New Data](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=data_dot_com_clean_company_info_rule_status_lex.htm&type=5) standard button on layouts that hadn't been fully updated from Classic. **What threw me off was that there's two different buttons in the XML even though only one button appears in the layout editor.**

It seems there were some layouts where the predefined actions were not overridden in Lightning and you can see that standard button is included in the Classic standard buttons.

Confirmed by removing that standard button and seeing the following removed from the XML

```
<excludeButtons>DataDotComClean</excludeButtons>
<excludeButtons>RequestUseSfdc</excludeButtons>
```